# Can't change the header of Hub control in Windows Universal app

Tags: windows, xaml, header, universal

I'm having problem with changing header of the Hub Control in Windows Universal app. I'm attaching screenshots so you would be able to see how it looks like.
[image: Hub Header in Visual Studio Designer]

As you can see at screenshot I changed header text to "Test Header" in XAML and I can see all changes in VS Designer. Problem is when I compile the app and deploy it on device or emulator because than header still contains default text "application name"...
[image]

What am I doing wrong?? I tried to creat new project, I was searching for "application name" string or some binding in my project but with no luck... :( Please help guys because I'm struggling with this for a few days now and I have no idea what to do.

Thanks in advance! Regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `x:Uid="Hub"` from the Hub control.

```
<Hub x:Name="Hub" Header="Test Header"/>
```

That way it won't redirect all your strings to the `Strings\en-US\Resources.resw` file (it is part of the shared project)

If you want to keep it in, then just edit that file and rename the key to anything you like.

[image]